# how can we keep csv file name dynamically, i have a dataframe final_result i have save it as a csv file with a dynamic name based on some variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
currentYear=int(time.strftime("%y", time.localtime()))-1
baseQuarter=4 #(it can be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4)

filename = "Q"+str(baseQuarter)+"-"+str(currentYear)+" ChronicNonFunnel"
filename=Q4-19 ChronicNonFunnel

final_result_Chronic(let say final_result_chronic is a dataframe)
final_result_Chronic=final_result_Chronic.to_csv('/home/developer/CustRetAnuragData/filename.csv'index = None)
```

**i want my csv filename saved with Q4-19 ChronicNonFunnel**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable filename has to be a string

```
filename = 'Q4-19 ChronicNonFunnel'
```

you can use string concatenation to save the file with the name in variable filename and extension as .csv

```
final_result_Chronic=final_result_Chronic.to_csv('/home/developer/CustRetAnuragData/'+filename+'.csv', index = None)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
final_result_Chronic.to_csv(f'/home/developer/CustRetAnuragData/{filename}.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
.
.
filename = 'Q4-19 ChronicNonFunnel'
.
.
final_result_Chronic.to_csv(os.path.join('/home/developer/CustRetAnuragData',"{}.csv".format(filename)))
```